# Playframework: How to add new database connections post server startup?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

How do I add a new database connection with ebean and pool support after a playframework 2.5 web app is initialized?  Playframework starts with a default db connection and while it is running I need to connect to a few other databases.

I can use Ebean.register(EbeanServer server, boolean defaultServer) to register a new datasource and use it with Ebean.getServer("dbConfigName").  But how do I specify the HikariCP pool configuration for this database?  Would Play use the HikariCP defaults from [play.db.prototype.HikariCP](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsJDBC)?